# PHP session variables not found Undefined index: is_user_login

Tags: php

The session variables are not set. My website was working until last month. We haven't made any code change and all of a sudden login is not working and it is because the session variables are not being set. As you can see in the code below, on querying the db for the emailaddress, the user is redirected to dashboard but there the variable is_user_login is not found. Could there be any configuration change that occured during the month perhaps that could cause this.

```
       if ($val->result_id->num_rows == 1) {
            foreach ($val->result_array() as $recs => $res) {
                $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                    'id' => $res['id'],
                    'email' => $res['email'],
                    'is_user_login' => true
                    )
                );
                $_SESSION['is_user_login'] = true;
            }
            redirect('dashboard');
          }
```

[image]

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {
public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
     $f = basename(__FILE__);
    error_log("Inside file before: $f and is user currently logged in: {$this->session->userdata('is_user_login')}");
   if (!$this->session->userdata('is_user_login')) {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

When I print the session variable in the next page, it is empty.

UPDATE:
I had to upgrade codeigniter from 3.0.6 to latest version. This solved the issue.

Comment: The folder pointed to by `session.save_path` PHP config variable should have write permissions for the Linux user that PHP-FPM is running under.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Website is hosted in cpanel. Can you tell me where I can set this.

Comment: what php version, have you upgraded php ?

Comment: PHP 7.4 (ea-php74) . Earlier it was 7.3 and since it was not working since last year, I updated it today to 7.4 to see if that makes a  difference.

Comment: make a file call it `phpinfo.php` and write in it `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then you can see what the status of the session is. maybe post here relevant lines with session variables

Comment: Max, I added my session related info

Answer (score 1):

This php configuration is OK

if this is really true that the session is not working then you must probably start the sessions.

I would now include a little code to see what the situation is:

```php
// include this code somewhere in your site into the same class 
protected function check_session($f,$l){
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    error_log("Sessions are enabled, but no session has been started in file:$f line:$l");
  }else if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_DISABLED) {
    error_log("Sessions are currently disabled in file:$f line:$l");
  }else if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    error_log("Sessions are enabled and a session has been started in file:$f line:$l");
  }
}


if ($val->result_id->num_rows == 1) {
  
  // then check status of sessions
  $this->check_session(basename(__FILE__),__LINE__);
  
  foreach ($val->result_array() as $recs => $res) {
    $this->session->set_userdata(array(
      'id' => $res['id'],
      'email' => $res['email'],
      'is_user_login' => true
      )
    );
    $_SESSION['is_user_login'] = true;
  }
  redirect('dashboard');
}
```

if your sessions are enabled but not started then you need to start them.

if the sessions are not enabled then you need to enable them.

Comment: The check session function returned ] "Sessions are enabled and a session has been started in file:Login.php line:46". I am going to put some more debug statements to see whats going on. The variable "is_user_login" is not true in subsequent pages.

Comment: When I try to print session variable in the next page it is empty. I have updated my question with the code in the next page.